# Java Eclipse "process" not ending after closing application

Tags: java, swing, opencv, jframe, webcam

I am writing an application that displays webcam connected to my computer.
I will just write code here since the code is very simple.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrameImageDisplayer _window = new JFrameImageDisplayer();
    //webcamGrabber _wg = new webcamGrabber(); 
    //commented out because I am having trouble with this class.
}
```

JFrameImageDisplayer opens a frame, pretty much that's all it does.
When I run this code, I open a simple application with a JLabel in the frame. If I close the application, then the whole process terminates( and the process at the Windows Task Manager Process tab processes as well).

However once I create _wg, the process at the Task Manager does not terminate even after I close the application ending up just burning processing power until I manually go to process bar to end it.

Below is the construction code for the webcamGrabber.

```
{
    OpenCVFrameGrabber _grab = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
    try{
        _grab.start();

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you releasing the resources associated with `_grab` object on close event of your JFrame?

Comment: That sounds like what I am supposed to do. No I am not releasing anything. Am I supposed to release it manually? I thought everything kinda evaporates once I close the application? I am new to application development. Could you please add a bit more info?

Comment: `Am I supposed to release it manually?` : That depends on the Api/class you are using. May be the `OpenCVFrameGrabber` author already had taken care of that, you'l have to look into it's documentation about releasing resources.

Comment: Also include it's links to your question, so that interested people can see it's code.

Comment: I think you were right, the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412050/java-webcam-application-keeps-running-in-the-background?rq=1 states the similar issue that I am having. However My class, webcamGrabber, runs without the Jframe in it, so i need a way to release it once the window is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I was not so sure what do. So I manually released the resources.

```
protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e){
    if(e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
        try{_wg._grab.release();}
        catch(Exception ee){}
    }
    super.processWindowEvent(e);
}
```

Not the prettiest way to do it, but it works.